# How to record a CheckBox Caption in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

**Background**

I have a `UserForm` named `Select_Fields` that allows the user to select columns from an inner join on two MS SQL database tables. I've built the `UserForm` with two `Frame`s containing `CheckBox`es for each column in the inner join.

I am able to connect to the database and display the data fine, but my attempts to put a header row above the data have been futile.

**Problem**

I am trying to get the `Caption` of the first `CheckBox` that has a value of `True` and write it to `cur.Value`, and then move `cur` one cell to the right for the next pass. I have code that looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Dim cmd As String
    Dim ctl As Control
    Set cur = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    ...
    For Each ctl In Select_Fields.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctl Then
                Select Case ctl.Name
                    Case "chkFoo"
                        cmd = cmd & "a.Foo"
                    Case "chkBar"
                        cmd = cmd & "b.Bar"
                    ...
                End Select
                cur.Value = ctl.Caption
                cur = cur.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
    ...
End Sub
```

The problem is in these two lines:

```
cur.Value = ctl.Caption
cur = cur.Offset(0, 1)
```

I keep getting an error at this point saying *"Run-time error '424': Object required"*, which I understand to mean that I have a type mismatch. **How do I write the `Caption` of a `CheckBox` to a cell's `Value`, and then move that cell pointer to the next one in line?**

Comment: have you tried just storing the caption in a `String` and then setting `cur.Value = CaptionString` ...VBA is annoying with that kind of stuff...

Comment: It gives the same error on the line `cur.Value = str`.

Comment: It's almost like `cur` isn't actually pointing to a cell, even though it's explicitly set.

Comment: ah well at least that proves that its `cur.Value` that is throwing the error and not `ctl.Caption` hmm....

Comment: I tried `cur.Text` as well, but with no luck

Comment: To test if a raw string would work, I tried assigning `cur.Value = "Test"` and it failed likewise. It's definitely `cur.Value` that's borken.

Comment: try `cur.Formula` or `cur.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: Both do the same thing

Comment: is there any code after the `Set cur = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` and before the `For Each..` that effects `cur`?

Comment: Perhaps. Before going through the `For Each` loop, I delete all rows from 4 down. (In the live code, it's actually cell A4 where I'm writing the header, but for simplicity I changed it to A1 here.) That code looks like this:

Comment: `With ActiveSheet Rows("4:" & .Rows.Count).Delete End With`

Comment: Can you try and set `cur` back to the proper cell _after_ the deletion and see if that fixes it?

Comment: On a whim, I moved that block above the `Set` assignment of `cur`, and it at least got through the first header before failing.

Comment: So, it's possibly the `cur = cur.Offset(0, 1)` line that's actually the problem, then. How do I go about moving the `cur` pointer to the next cell?

Comment: Ah, it needs to be `Set cur = cur.Offset(0, 1)` gotta love vba

Comment: OH. MY. GOD. Like, six hours, down the toilet. Convert your answer to a comment so I can give you the points you deserve. And THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad we got it solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as we discussed in the comments, make sure that `cur` actually still points to the proper cell after your deletion occurs and then remember to use the `Set` keyword when assigning objects in vba:

```
Set cur = cur.Offset(0, 1)
```